# In Jquery, how do I alert the value of a regular element with an id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getvalue

```
   <!doctype html>
 <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){var mainVal = $("#h1").valueOf();alert(mainVal);})</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1 id="h1" value="0">hallow you </h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I am trying to use the val() method here. Any help would be awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you've use `.valueOf()` (its a different js methoud and here is its docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf ) it should be `.val()` which is used to get the values of `form` elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`, for more info check the docs here: https://api.jquery.com/val/

second, to get the value from the `value` attribute in an element you need to use the `.attr('attribute-name')` method

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var mainVal = $("#h1").attr("value");
    alert(mainVal);
  })
```